# Determine if cursor position is on start of a defined row in textarea

Tags: javascript

How to determine if cursor position is on start of a defined row in textarea with JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea

Comment: Nope ;) He wants to get cursor position in textarea ,I - to determine if the cursor is on start on defined row (e.g 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer provided here:

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

you can get the offset of the cursor position in the text. After you have that, you can count the newline characters present in the text of the `<textarea>` before the offset to figure out which line you are on. If the offset is just after a newline, then you're at the start of the row. Using these two methods, you should be able to figure out if you are at the start of a specific line. For example:

```
var offset = getCaret('mytextarea');
var text = document.getElementById('mytextarea').value;
var line_number = 1;
var i;

for ( i = 0; i < offset; i++ ) {
    if ( text[i] == '\n' ) {
        line_number++;
    }
}

if ( !i || text[i-1] == '\n' ) {
    // You're at the start of a line
}
```

Note: IE might use carriage returns (\r) as well, so you may have to account for them.

Comment: I have code ,which determines on which row(line) is the cursor ,but how to check if it's on the start of this row?

Comment: If there's 'soft-wrap' this won't work for long lines that were wrapped. (I'm looking for a good solution to this issue but no luck so far.)

Answer (score -1):

You could use one or a combination of the on events: `onchange`, `onkeyup`, `onkeydown`, `onkeypress`.

Provide a little more detail on your overall goal.

Comment: `onchange` will only fire when an input control loses focus *and* its value has been modified since gaining focus. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange

Comment: Without additional specification in the OP, I was providing options. Who knows what on events may be helpful.

Comment: OK ,I could use onkeydown ,but how to do the check?

Comment: – As `onchange` will not fire when a field is not changed, the user can simply move the cursor to the beginning of a row of a `textarea` without this JavaScript event being fired. Though the OP is not very clear in his goal(s), it is understandable that that's not the intended behaviour. Not my down vote, BTW.